# How to toast an error message of validation shows that no item from a spinner is selected?

Tags: java, android

How to toast an error message of validation shows that no item from a spinner is selected? Below coding works BUT when I select one of the item, the toast message will be displayed as well. Can someone please help me, which part do I miss?

```
    if(RegisterUserType.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Select the options listed, either parents or tuition provider.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Coding for spinner setting adapter:-

```
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add(0, "Choose Category");
    categories.add("Parents");
    categories.add("Tuition Provider");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    RegisterUserType.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    RegisterUserType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Chooose Category"))
            {
                //Do Nothing
            }

            else
            {
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), item +" selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes. But it would be better if you use equalIgnoreCase() instead of equals() as case doesn't matter here

Comment: @VivekMishra why should I using the ignoreCase sir? Is it not just for text?

Comment: You have currently written "Choose Category". Suppose later you changed it to "choose category", then equals() will return false while ignorecase will still return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can perform your requirements like,
In your Activity's Oncreate(),

```
    ArrayList<String> countries=new ArrayList<>();
        countries.add("Select Country");
        countries.add("India");
        countries.add("China");
        countries.add("USA");
        countries.add("Africa");
        countries.add("Russia");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
    RegisterUserType.setAdapter(adapter);

    RegisterUserType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Item Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item Selected = "+parent.getItemAtPosition(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a item in your spinner 0th position.

```
spinnerList.add("Please choose one");
```

Now check if selected position is not 0.

```
if(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0){
  // show error toast
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a first item dummy to the array you are passing into spinner.

For e.g. Add "Select Item"

then check if selected position==0
Display Toast

Answer (score 0):

you can use `spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()` for this.

to handle this just add a dummy value with your arrayList like this.

```
arraylist.add("Select item");
```

and then your other data

```
    arraylist.add("ABC");
    arraylist.add("XYZ");
    arraylist.add("BCA");
```

for checking validation use

```
if(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)
{
Toast.makeText(this,"Please select an item",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```